# Twitter-like app using MongoDB

Tags: database-design, mongodb, software-design

I'm making an app that uses the classic "follow" mechanism (the one used by Twitter and a lot of other apps around the web). I'm using MongoDB.
My system has a difference, though: an user can follow *groups* of users. That means that if you follow a group, you'll automatically follow all the users who are members of that group.  Of course users can belong to more than one group.

This is what I came up with:

- when **user A** follows **user B**, id of user B gets added to an embedded array (called `following`) in user A's document
- for unfollowing, I remove the id of the followed user from the `following` array
- groups work in the same way: when **user A** follows **group X**, id of group X gets added to the `following` array. (I actually add a `DBRef` so I know if the connection is to an user or a group.)
- when I have to check if **user A** follows **group X**, I just search for the group's id in **user A**'s following array.
- when I have to check if **user A** follows **user B**, things gets a little trickier. Each user's document has an embedded array listing all the groups the user belongs to. So I use an `$or` condition to check if user A is either following user B directly or via a group. Like this:

  > `db.users.find({'$or':{'following.ref.$id':$user_id,'following.ref.$ref','users'},{'following.ref.$id':{'$in':$group_ids},'following.ref.$ref':'groups'}}})`

This works fine, but I think I have a few issues. For example how do I show a list of followers for a particular user, including pagination? I can't use skip() and limit() on an embedded document.

I could change the design and use an `userfollow` collection, which would do the same job of the embedded `following` document. The problem with this approach, which I tried, is that with the `$or` condition I used earlier, users following two groups containing the same user would be listed twice. To avoid this I could use group or MapReduce, which I actually did and it works, but I'd love to avoid this to keep things simpler. Maybe I just need to think out of the box. Or maybe I took the wrong approach with both tries. Anyone already had to do a similar thing and came up with a better solution?

(This is actually a follow-up to [this older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838466/making-a-twitter-like-timeline-with-mongodb) of mine. I decided to post a new question to explain my new situation better; I hope it's not a problem.)

Comment: My vote is on using map to write the follower list out to a temporary collection

Comment: I heard Map/Reduce can be slow, so I can't do it on every page load. That means follower lists wouldn't be up-to-date, so I'd prefer to avoid this solution...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have two possible ways in which a user can follow another user; either directly, or indirectly through a group, in which case the user *directly* follows the group. Let's begin with storing these *direct* relations between users and groups:

```
{
  _id: "userA",
  followingUsers: [ "userB", "userC" ],
  followingGroups: [ "groupX", "groupY" ]
}
```

Now, you'll want to be able to *quickly* find out which users user A is following, either directly or indirectly. To achieve this, you can denormalize the groups that user A is following. Let's say that group X and Y are defined as follows:

```
{
  _id: "groupX",
  members: [ "userC", "userD" ]
},
{
  _id: "groupY",
  members: [ "userD", "userE" ]
}
```

Based on these groups, and the direct relations user A has, you can generate **subscriptions** between users. The origin(s) of a subscription are stored with each subscription. For the example data the subscriptions would look like this:

```
// abusing exclamation mark to indicate a direct relation
{ ownerId: "userA", userId: "userB", origins: [ "!" ] },
{ ownerId: "userA", userId: "userC", origins: [ "!", "groupX" ] },
{ ownerId: "userA", userId: "userD", origins: [ "groupX", "groupY" ] },
{ ownerId: "userA", userId: "userE", origins: [ "groupY" ] }
```

You can generate these subscriptions pretty easily, using a map-reduce-finalize call for an individual user. If a group is updated, you only have to re-run the map-reduce for all users that are following the group and the subscriptions will be up-to-date again.

#### Map-reduce

The following map-reduce functions will generate the subscriptions for a single user.

```
map = function () {
  ownerId = this._id;

  this.followingUsers.forEach(function (userId) {
    emit({ ownerId: ownerId, userId: userId } , { origins: [ "!" ] });
  });

  this.followingGroups.forEach(function (groupId) {
    group = db.groups.findOne({ _id: groupId });

    group.members.forEach(function (userId) {
      emit({ ownerId: ownerId, userId: userId } , { origins: [ group._id ] });
    });
  });
}

reduce = function (key, values) {
  origins = [];

  values.forEach(function (value) {
    origins = origins.concat(value.origins);
  });

  return { origins: origins };
}

finalize = function (key, value) {
  db.subscriptions.update(key, { $set: { origins: value.origins }}, true);
}
```

You can then run the map-reduce for a single user, by specifying a query, in this case for `userA`.

```
db.users.mapReduce(map, reduce, { finalize: finalize, query: { _id: "userA" }})
```

A few notes:

- You should delete the previous subscriptions of a user, before running map-reduce for that user.
- If you update a group, you should run map-reduce for all the users that follow the group.

I should note that these map-reduce functions turned out to be **more complex than what I had in mind**, because MongoDB doesn't support arrays as return values of reduce functions. In theory, the functions *could* be much simpler, but wouldn't be compatible with MongoDB. However, this more complex solution can be used to map-reduce the entire `users` collection in a single call, if you ever have to.

Comment: This sounds like a good solution, thanks. The pagination problem is still there though: I can't use skip()/limit() with embedded documents. Basically as I said in the question, I need to list all the stuff an user is following (pretty much like Twitter does).

Comment: @Brainfeeder: You could store each subscription as a document in a separate collection to get around the skip/limit limitation. Then `"userA"` would be the `ownerId` for each of the subscriptions I mentioned, e.g. `{ ownerId: "userA", userId: "userB", origins: [ "!" ] }`.

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Niels van der Rest: One thing: when should I run the Map/Reduce? Every time user A follows an user/group? Sorry, I'm still a bit confused about this as I'm new to NoSQL.

Comment: @Niels van der Rest: sorry to bother you, but what do you think about this related question I wrote a while ago? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838466/making-a-twitter-like-timeline-with-mongodb Thanks.

Comment: Also, one more thing. They say Map/Reduce shouldn't be used in realtime, because of it slowness. Could this be a problem for my app? Especially in the future, when the number of users, followers and groups will hopefully be pretty high?

Comment: @Brainfeeder: That's only the case for map-reduce on entire collections. But your map-reduce will only target a single user at a time. You're not map-reducing the entire `users` collection, but only a single document, so it shouldn't be slow. I'll update my answer with an example and have a look at your other question.

Comment: @Brainfeeder: I've updated my answer, although it turned out to be a little more complex than what I had in mind. Regarding your other question: I agree with the posted answers. I've thought about that question before, but couldn't see any other efficient solution. In this question, map-reduce solves the need to differentiate between users and groups. But in the other question there is no such complexity, so using map-reduce wouldn't add any value :)

Comment: Thanks for the massive answer, it all makes much more sense now. I was actually trying to write the MapReduce myself but I didn't even think I could use the finalize function to update the subscriptions collection, so... Anyway, I'm curious about why the functions are more complex than you initially thought. I'm just wondering how could they be simpler if MongoDB supported arrays as a return value? Sorry if I'm feeling kind of devoid of thoughts on this at the moment.

Comment: @Brainfeeder: You're welcome. In theory, the map function should just emit the `_id` of the followed user as the key, and the origin (direct or group) as the value. MongoDB then merges all these origins into a single array for each key, which is exactly what we need. So for user C the merged array would be `[ "!", "groupX" ]`. But you aren't allowed to simply return this array from the reduce function; you can only return a single value or object. But this returned value is then added to the array as well, which makes the final result incorrect.

Comment: @Brainfeeder: To work around this, I had to introduce an object to hold the `origins` array and merge the values myself in the reduce function, using the `concat()` function.

Comment: @Niels van der Rest: Finally that makes sense. I'm glad I asked my last question, I learned quite a lot thinking about it.

Comment: @Niels van der Rest: I just realized I also need to list all the groups an user is following. What do you think about storing relations between users and groups in another collection (thus duplicating the followingGroups embedded array)?

Comment: @Brainfeeder: I can't think of a good reason why you want to save the group relations in a separate collection just yet. A query on `groups` based on the IDs in the `followingGroups` array should be fast enough, in case you need additional group info, such as a name or description. If you see that this query is forming a bottleneck, then you should think about map-reducing it into a separate collection, or duplicate the required group properties directly to the `followingGroups` array.

Comment: @Niels van der Rest: Yeah, I was a bit concerned about performance, but after all it's not like this structure is set in stone. I can always adapt it in the future if it turns out to be slow with a lot of users. So I'll go with what you suggested. Thanks again.