# In MongoDB, how do I query for something similar to Twitter?

Tags: mysql, mongodb, database, nosql

Suppose I follow users 4, 7, 10, and 20. How can I query that in Mongo?

```
db.all_posts.find(users = 4, 7, 10, 20).sort( by date )
```

I don't know the right syntax.  Is this scalable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`$in` operator](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24in) to match against multiple values:

```
db.all_posts.find({user: {$in: [4, 7, 10, 20]}}).sort({date: 1})
```

As you can see, the `find()`, [`sort()`](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%7B%7Bsort%28%29%7D%7D) and most other methods in MongoDB take in objects as parameters. These objects are called [query expression objects](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Querying#Querying-QueryExpressionObjects).

The question [Making a Twitter-like timeline with MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838466/making-a-twitter-like-timeline-with-mongodb) should answers your question about scalability, as it discusses the same data model as yours.